# Let $G$ be a group such that $G = (\mathbb{R}, +)$, $H = \{x\in \mathbb{R}$: tan $x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$. Is $(H,+)$ a subgroup of $(G,+)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $G = (\mathbb{R}, +)$, $H = \{x\in \mathbb{R}$: tan $x \in \mathbb{Q}     \}$.  Is $(H,+)$ a subgroup of $(G,+)$?

The hint I've been given is to use the following identity:

tan($x+y$) = $\large \frac{\rm{tan} x + \rm{tan} y}{1-\rm{tan}x *\rm{tan}y}$.

So I need to show that for $a,b \in H$ that ($a^{-1} + b) \in H$.
Since the operation is  + , then $a^{-1}$ = $-a$ = -tan $x$.

So -tan $x$ + tan $y$ is where I am.
How do I get from there to the identity I am supposed to use?

Comment: No, you're at $\mathrm{tan}(-x+y)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Your identity implies closure of addition everywhere except when the denominator is $0$. Look for a counter-example where $x\in H$ and $y\in H$ but $x+y\notin H$.

Spoiler:

> Consider $x = \arctan(1/2)$ and $y=\arctan(2)$. Then $x\in H$ and $y\in H$ since $\tan(x) = 1/2$ and $\tan(y) = 2$ by definition. But $x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ so $\tan(x+y)$ is undefined. Therefore your set $H$ is not closed under addition and hence is not a subgroup.

Comment: don't you mean set $\mathbb{H}$ is not closed ?

Comment: @dibyendu Ah yes, I confused $H$ with $G$.